# Softmax classifier with class priors

Tags: logistic, generative-models, softmax

Softmax classifier is a discriminative model that directly models $p(Y|X, w)$ where $Y$ is the label for input $X$. We can write it as follows:

$$p(y_i=k|x_i,w_k)=\frac{\exp \lbrace w_k^T x_i \rbrace}{\sum_{j=1}^K \exp\lbrace w_j^T x_i\rbrace}$$

How can we use this in a generative setting by defining priors over class labels such as a Markov random field? How can we formulate the joint density $p(X,Y|w) = p(X|Y,w)p(Y)$, or the posterior $p(Y|X,w)$ while the likelihood is already in the form $p(Y|X,w)$?